# Why does my code not work? -Zooming in Chart Control-

Tags: vb.net, charts, zooming, mousewheel

```
Private Sub DrawChart()
    'this is only part of the chart drawing setup

    With Chart1.ChartAreas(0)

        .AxisX.Maximum = ChartAxisXMax + ZoomFactor
        .AxisX.Minimum = ChartAxisXMin + ZoomFactor
        .AxisY.Minimum = ChartAxisXMax + ZoomFactor
        .AxisY.Maximum = ChartAxisXMax + ZoomFactor

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Chart1_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseWheel
    ZoomFactor = e.Delta * SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines / 100 ' WHEEL_DATA
    DrawChart()

End Sub
```

Am I putting it in the wrong place maybe? Is the event not triggered as soon as I scroll the mouse? The Axes Minimum and Maximum are already preset so whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code:

```
Private Sub Chart1_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseWheel
        Dim ZoomFactor = e.Delta * SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines / 100 ' WHEEL_DATA

        With Chart1.ChartAreas(0)

            .AxisX.Maximum = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum - ZoomFactor
            .AxisX.Minimum = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum + ZoomFactor
            .AxisY.Minimum = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Minimum + ZoomFactor
            .AxisY.Maximum = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum - ZoomFactor

        End With

    End Sub
```